# how to find nth minimum/maximum of all subarrays of size k (Sliding window problem)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

There are so many reference to find minimum/maximum of all subarrays of size k but how to find nth maximum/minimum in best possible way.
If we have to find just min/max of subarrays, then we can use deque solution with linear time complexity. But for nth min/max, I am not able to find the solution.

Note: n<=k

Example:
arr = {7,1,4,20,11,17,15}
n=2, k=4

output: 4,4,11,15

Comment: Questions should be self contained. What is your approach?

Comment: What do you mean by better? Deterministic linear time? Lower constant factor?

Comment: @user202729 I mentioned my approach. Should I elaborate more?

Comment: @user202729 Just want to know, what is the best approach for this problem. Like can I modify sliding window problem' solution using deque and things get done. I mean if we can solve this in linear time.

Comment: Please provide any needed information from linked articles in the body of the question. Links can break. (It might also help us all organise our thoughts around what's important for this question.)

Comment: Ok. I will remove link and will update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the data structure you need is a little modified Binary Search Tree (BST), where each node also stores the size of it's subtree.

Adding, removing elements or [finding nth element](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-k-th-smallest-element-in-bst-order-statistics-in-bst/) in a BST all then becomes `log(K)`*. So while sliding the window over your array, you have 3 `log(K)` operations, assuming total `N` elements in given array, the overall time complexity is therefore `N*log(K)`.

- You need a balanced BST (Red Black Tree for example) to maintain this time complexity. If you are coming from any online judges like Codeforce or Hackerrank, remember they more often than not provide inputs that will generate degenerate BSTs.

Comment: Voted this up, but I'm not convinced we can't shave the log factor.

Comment: Thanks, honestly I'm not convinced either